# When I try to call port 80 python program stop and says permission denied when ms.bind((host,port))

Tags: sockets

```
import socket
ms=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host="192.168.0.159"
port=80
ms.bind((host, port))
ms.listen(5)

while True: 
  conn,addr=ms.accept()
  data=conn.recv(1000)
  if not data:
      break

  print (data)
  print ("Got a request!\n")

conn.close()
ms.close()
```

Comment: You will most likely find that port 80 is being used by another process. You should check if any other programs have bound to port 80.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind to ports below 1024 without the CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE capability. The root user has it.

Or, you can assign it to an executable with

`$ sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/program`

But, caveat, the latter does not work for scripts. You had to add the capability to the interpreter itself, which is a huge security hole. Don't do that.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps using flask or websockets to expect data on port 80 (if it is not in use) may be a better option.